# How to force MSI uninstall?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installer

I found a lot of components (EXEs/DLLs, .NET assemblies, and registry entries) left behind on my PC from an ancient install and uninstall of VS2012. I want to cleanly get rid of them all using their MSI files which are still in my Package Cache but `msiexec /x product.msi` just gives me `This action is only valid for products that are installed`, presumably because the main VS2012 installer deleted it's product codes from the Installer data and the MSI thinks the product is not installed.

Is it possible to bypass this validation check with an `msiexec` command line switch? Or is there a tool to scan the MSI and delete everything it installed? I looked at `msizap` but it only deletes the installer data for the product, not all the crap it installed.

TL;DR: is there a tool which does:

`for item in product.msi do delete $item`

Comment: You forget one little detail: usually the initial VS installation has been changed multiple times by updates, upgrades and so on, so even if you could delete every single file installed by that MSI file there would be leftovers as the MSI does not cover your complete installation.

Answer (score 1):

As you uninstalled the product once, which uses the uninstaller,
a second uninstall would probably not do better.
Also, most of these leftovers were probably created when using the product,
after the installation.

It would be better to install the product again and then use an uninstaller
such as
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/)
to uninstall and clean afterward.
Unfortunately, installing and uninstalling VS is not a fast operation.

From my experience, if you have more than one Visual Studio version
installed, using Revo might clean out too much, because some components
may be common to more than one version.

My advice in the case of having multiple VS versions,
would be to accept the presence of some leftovers and only use the
official uninstaller. You may safely verify that the installation folder
of VS2012 has been cleared out, but leave alone the other components.

Comment: Third-party uninstallers are not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: In that case, follow the second part of my answer.